# Redirect to a link using the default broswser in Windows Form based application

Tags: forms, redirect, hyperlink

I am not use: Process.Start (String, String) to open a link. But every time the browser open a new tab or new window to open the link.
Is there a way that to open the link in the latest opened page? Just redirection, no new tab or new window?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really up to you (the programmer) to decide but to the user: Some browsers have an option for this setting. You shouldn't try modifying the user's selected browser behaviour.

Someone of my team did this once in an instant messenger application that we were writing, without asking for other opinions first. The users were super annoyed that our application kept overwriting their opened pages.